# wget & curl can't download a specific CSS file

Tags: css, bash, shell, curl, wget

I'm trying to download a CSS file using wget - quite a simple task I would say,
but whenever I try downloading the CSS file I receive a corrupted/mis-formatted file, containing lines like these:

```
wں��_�m�^{���|&�gC�H�4�I�d�޳�m����V��;��%Y6�w��K�K#i4��F#���D�g;�J`FO�ꪲ�l׉+��_D�s`�JU7�D��w*ފ��W^;�r�t�a���<��M�t�c?\N<�v���_���&0��7����P{�י���M63Ӷ���U�V9�V���Me匞<(ҜU&�;��7�X����9�f�ܙ�(�=gv�B����C�T��ϕ�i=!��yhZ��t��2'��M��}o�C�8�7�pW�f����
```

[Here is the source CSS file](http://daks2k3a4ib2z.cloudfront.net/56938a33feb451344a7acab7/css/compass-hls.eedd6aab0.min.css)

The things is: downloading other files works just fine, there must be something wrong specifically with this file...

I tried updating wget - same output.

Tried using curl - same output.

I'd appreciate any help! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the file with `wget` and check it with `file`:

```
$ wget -O foo.css http://daks2k3a4ib2z.cloudfront.net/56938a33feb451344a7acab7/css/compass-hls.eedd6aab0.min.css

$ file foo.css
foo.css: gzip compressed data, from Unix
```

---

Download the file with wget, write it to stdout, uncompress it, write it to a file and check it with `file`:

```
$ wget -O - http://daks2k3a4ib2z.cloudfront.net/56938a33feb451344a7acab7/css/compass-hls.eedd6aab0.min.css | gunzip > foo.css

$ file foo.css
foo.css: ASCII text, with very long lines, with no line terminators
```

Comment: On my machine, the upzip part isn't necessary. using wget by itself is enough, or even opening the URL directly from Kate.

Comment: Figured it out myself just before you wrote it haha! But thanks allot nevertheless :) Really appreciate the help * reassurance!

Answer (score 4):

The server is serving a gzip compressed file to reduce the amount of data that is sent. It might not be doing that for everything it serves, but it certainly is for this file.

You can use the --compressed curl option to uncompress what it returns:

```
curl --compressed "http://daks2k3a4ib2z.cloudfront.net/56938a33feb451344a7acab7/css/compass-hls.eedd6aab0.min.css"
```